# Excel: Interior.ColorIndex producing different values for same index

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I want to set a range of cells to have a grey interior. The grey I want comes right after Black and White on the pallete (top row, third from the left).

I set a cell's interior to this colour manually, then used vba to MsgBox the ColourIndex. It came up with 19. However, when i set a cell's Interior.ColorIndex property to equal 19, the cell is not grey but an off-white/cream colour.

So much that the following code actually changes a cell's (cell A1's) color from grey to cream:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A1")

Dim n As Integer

n = r.Interior.ColorIndex

r.Interior.ColorIndex = n
```

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: [Related question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259995/different-color-but-same-color-index-in-excel-vba/11265978)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `ColorIndex` only supports a [limited number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc296089%28v=office.12%29.aspx#xlDiscoveringColorIndex_ColorIndexProperty) of colors. Try this instead:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim n As Long ' The return values are large, so Integer will overflow

Set r = Range("A1")

' The color is 14806254
n = r.Interior.Color
r.Interior.Color = n
```

Or for your actual purpose:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim n As Long

myRange = Range("A1:F1")
n = 14806254

' Color away!
For Each cell In myRange
  cell.Interior.Color = n
Next cell
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set the themecolor.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A1")

Dim n As Integer

n = r.Interior.ColorIndex

With r.Interior
    .ColorIndex = n
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
End With
```