# Setting cell (n) Color Index equal to cell (n - 1) Color Index

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a weird output from this macro. The macro should fill the blank cells with the color above creating a block of colors. The result is not what I expected even though `Debug.Print` shows the same `ColorIndex` number.

**Any idea what is happening here?**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Crayon()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim MyCell As Range

For Each MyCell In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If MyCell.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then
        If MyCell.Offset(-1).Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142 Then
            MyCell.Interior.ColorIndex = MyCell.Offset(-1).Interior.ColorIndex
        End If
    End If
Next MyCell

End Sub
```

I used to following macro to produce `Column G` on the photo, which shows color index for each cell produced by the above macro `Crayon`. I am not sure how to explain the output of **mismatched colors** with **identical color indexes**.

```
Sub Index_Output()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i

For i = 2 To 17
    ws.Range("G" & i) = ws.Range("C" & i).Interior.ColorIndex
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

P.S. this was my attempt to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868671/need-excel-vba-code-to-color-cell-as-above-if-no-fill) question as this is how I learn/practice VBA :)

Comment: *extra points not available for solution from color blind user*

Comment: `ColorIndex` is limited, since it is "specified as an _index value into the current [limited] color palette_."  See [MSDN - Color Index property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/colorindex-property) and [Different color but same color index in excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259995/different-color-but-same-color-index-in-excel-vba)

Comment: So you should be using `Color` instead of `ColorIndex` - colors from different palettes can have the same index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The varying colors is due to the nature of `ColorIndex`, which as [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/colorindex-property) notes represents the index of a color in a palette. Colors from different palettes will have the same index number, so use `Color` instead of `ColorIndex`.

Change `ColorIndex` to `Color` within the innermost `If...End IF`.

```
Sub Crayon()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim MyCell As Range

For Each MyCell In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If MyCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
        If MyCell.Offset(-1).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
            MyCell.Interior.Color = MyCell.Offset(-1).Interior.Color
        End If
    End If
Next MyCell

End Sub
```