# Selecting range of visible cells only with VBA

Tags: vba, range, excel-2010, cell, visible

I have the following function "CountCcolor()" that I would like to use on a status tracker. My intention is to be able to use the function to find in a single columns range of visible cells how many are highlighted in a specific color, say green.

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long

    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long

    ' The next one-liner does not work. Without it, it selects visible and hidden cells. I only want it to select visible cells:
    range_data = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

    xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each datax In range_data
        If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
             CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
        End If
    Next datax
End Function
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Interior.ColorIndex`

Instead, just use `Interior.Color`. I was stumped by this once as well. In short, the `ColorIndex` represents a **palate** of colors, **not** a unique color. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869130/setting-cell-n-color-index-equal-to-cell-n-1-color-index) for more details

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria as Range) As Long

Dim myRange As Range, myCell As Range, TempCount As Long
Set myRange = range_data.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each myCell In myRange
    If myCell.Interior.Color = criteria.Interior.Color Then
        TempCount = TempCount + 1
    End If
Next myCell

CountCcolor = TempCount

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for first of all for cleaning out my code! short and sweet, as it should be :)  Unfortunately, I am still bumping into the problem with hidden cells: I am filtering a different column for a specific group of data and need to only choose the visible cells 2 columns over (that are highlighted green. I use this count of colored cell to calculate how many tasks got completed.

Comment: I can re-visit at EOD :)

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate all your help so far :)

Comment: I found someone else with the hidden cell problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351729/specialcellsxlcelltypevisible-also-includes-hidden-filtered-cells) but in their case they were able to resolve by changing the adjacent filtered column to the same format. In my case, I have: the filtered column are strings, and the column I need to only use visible cells are dates. I tried converting it all to text but to no avail.