# Font.ColorIndex not consistent across input and output

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following function which parses some formatting shet and returns a color index:

```
Function returnFontColor(targetString As String) As Integer

    Dim formatSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim counter As Integer

    returnFontColor = 0

    Set formatSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting")

    With formatSheet

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row

        For row = 2 To lastRow
            If LCase(CStr(.Range("B" & row).Value)) = LCase(CStr(targetString)) Then
                For counter = 1 To Len(.Range("C" & row).Value)
                    If .Range("C" & row).Characters(Start:=counter, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex <> 0 Then

                        returnFontColor = .Range("C" & row).Characters(Start:=counter, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex
                        GoTo Exiter
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
Exiter:

End Function
```

How I use the function:

```
ws.Cells(row_num, col_num).Font.ColorIndex = returnFontColor(name)
```

My issue is that the color I get from calling this function is significantly different than that of the formatting sheet, and I don't understand why because this should be relying on RGB which is very specific. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What values are you getting? Check here for a color index table: http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting cell (n) Color Index equal to cell (n - 1) Color Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869130/setting-cell-n-color-index-equal-to-cell-n-1-color-index)

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, it seems like this is indeed a duplicate question. It seems like I am not able to delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `Font.Color` instead of `Font.ColorIndex`.

The `index returns a pallet which can consist of MANY colors.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a color index is not the same thing as returning a color. The color index returns a position from the color palette, not the actual RGB color.

Often times cell fill colors are picked from the color drop down from the home menu. In that case, two workbooks with different Office Themes will display different colors despite the same color index.

To get the actual fill color, use the `Font.Color` method and return as a **Double** because the possible values are 0 to 256^3.